# Expecting a different type

Tags: haskell, types, casting

I am getting this when I compile my code in Haskell:

```
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Car a1 [Char]'
Expected type: [Car a1 [Char]]
Actual type: [[Char]]
```

I'm new at Haskell and not sure what this means. I've spent the past 45 mins searching for an answer and haven't found anything to help in my situation.

Here is the first error:

```
Couldn't match expected type '[[Char]]'
with actual type  'Car [Char] t0'
In the pattern: Leaf a
In an equation for 'evaluation': evaluation (Leaf a) = a
```

This is around the lines of code it is having a problem with. If you would like me to post more please let me know, Thanks.

```
evaluation (Leaf a) = a
evaluation (Breakpoint "j" []) = 0
evaluation (Breakpoint "j" x:xs) = evaluation (x) + evaluation (Breakpoint "j" xs)
```

Comment: Could you post the code you were trying to compile?

Comment: Please post the definition of the type that has the constructors `Leaf` and `Breakpoint`, and if you can the type signature for `evaluation`.

Comment: I found out what the problem ended up being. I was creating my own sum and product functions and they are already declared in the standard function and was giving me this error. This error came up when I tried to correct my code. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a function somewhere which wants (or thinks it wants) a list of `Car a1 String`, and is instead receiving a list of `String`. It's impossible to know how to address this without seeing some actual code, but a good starting point would be to add type annotations to your functions, so that you can see the first error - right now you're seeing something that eventually happens when Haskell's type inference finally gives up on your code.